# Take user input and print a floating point array in MIPS

Tags: mips

I need to take input from the user a floating point array and then print it. I tried the following code:-

```
.text
.globl main
main:

 la $s0,size
 lw $s1,0($s0)      # size in $s1
 ori $s2,$zero,0    # i in $s2
 la $s3,arr         # arr in $s3

 li $v0,4
 la $a0,msg1
 syscall

 L1:
  beq $s2,$s1,DONE
  li $v0,6
  syscall
  swc1 $f0,0($s3)
  j UPDATE

 UPDATE:
  addi $s3,$s3,4
  addi $s1,$s1,1
  j L1

 DONE:
  li $v0,4
  la $a0,msg2
  syscall

  la $t0,arr
  ori $t1,$zero,0
  L2:
   beq $t1,$s1,EXIT
   lwc1 $f20,0($t0)
   li $v0,2
   mov.s $f12,$f20
   syscall
   addi $t0,$t0,4
   addi $t1,$t1,1
   j L2

  EXIT:
  li $v0,10
  syscall
    .data
  size: .word  9
  arr:  .float  0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0 
  msg1: .asciiz "Enter the elements:-"
  msg2: .asciiz "The elements are:-"
```

When i give the input, there is a runtime exception 'invalid float input' at syscall 6. Please help!!!

Comment: If you have a helpful answer you should accept it. Click on checkmark under upvote/downvote counter. This will mark the question as "answered" and provide you with small reputation bonus. See [How do I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) FAQ article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using `,` as the decimal point instead of `.`.

E.g.: instead of entering `3.14159` you are entering `3,14159` which is not expected at least by MARS.

Aside from that, I think the line `addi $s1,$s1,1` in your code should be `addi $s2,$s2,1`, as you seem to be using `$s2` to hold the current value of your index counter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the silly error... It worked on changing $s1 to $s2.